# Why isn't this FFmpeg command for creating a video out of frames working?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

I have a series of files starting at `frame001.png` and ending at `frame580.png`. I tried to use the following command to compile them into an `mp4`:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i frame%03d.png ..\output.mp4
```

but the result is an empty video file with no frames in it at all. What am I doing wrong? This is the exact same command that the [official FFmpeg tutorial](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow) uses.

I should note that using the `-start_number` argument does not change anything.

If it helps, [here is the output](https://pastebin.com/x86XPf5T).

Comment: The output isn't empty. ffmpeg has auto selected yuv444p pixel format which isn't compatible with many players.

Answer (score 0):

The official tutorial explains that this command can solve the problem:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i frame%03d.png -c:v libx264 -vf fps=60 -pix_fmt yuv420p ..\output.mp4
```

This can be found under the subheader "[If your video does not show the frames correctly](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Ifyourvideodoesnotshowtheframescorrectly)".

Comment: `-vf fps=60` is not needed.